# android application using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good day.

I'm having an error with my android application. I can't delete the codes because the R.java is auto generated by eclipse.

Whenever i delete it, it restores the error. I need help. Here's the code that has the error.

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int 10_00=0x7f080021;
    public static final int 90=0x7f08001f;
```

Comment: what's the error exactly you have? the logcat may help you determine that the error is. R.java is design to be generated automatically. That's not a problem.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, it will automatically solved. project -> clean and project -> build

Comment: Better you know that R file is auto generated file. And are you sure that there are variable with names 10_00 and 90?

Comment: Normally, we won't edit anything inside R.java manually

Comment: try built path . You should not update R.java.

Comment: @PankajKumar Everytime Clean may not be the solution :)

Comment: I'v clean the project many times. Request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol.

Comment: the names are very strange, I mean, "10_00" and "90", pure numerbs should not be used as the name of variables. Is this the problem?

Comment: I'v fixed the problem. There are some textview with with ID of 10_100 and 90. I renamed it and the problem goes away. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani Actually when I got same problem solved by cleaning project. Thank you for updating me. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't know how to give variable names for resources or IDs in Android XML file.

The variable name should not start with number. It must start with alphabet. It should not contain any special characters which were used as tokens in XML file. (e.g., @, <, >, ?, etc.)

**Valid** : s12, hi, var_12, etc.

**Invalid** : 12s, 123, hi, s12#, etc.

The problem in your project is **your ID names started with numbers as 10_00 and 90**. Modify these to valid variable names.

I hope you understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Variable name cannot be started with number. Search for java code convention.

Answer (score 0):

or if it is showing error in specific file, resolve accordingly. If error is not displaying on specific files but on project, see Problems view in eclipse, and see the error and proceed accordingly. If Still, you are not able to resolve, put your issue.

Comment: I'v fixed the problem. There are some textview with with ID of 10_100 and 90. I renamed it and the problem goes away. Thank you so much